# What condition implies $g^{-1}(I \cap A) = g^{-1}(I) \cap A$?

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading a proof on the statement

> Suppose $f= g$ a.e. Then if $f \in M$ (measurable), so is $g$ (measurable).

The proof starts with $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, and we look at the presage of $g$. The goal was to, of course, show the preimage is a measurable set. From the outset, let $A = \{x \in X: f\neq g \}$ where $X$ is the universal set.

\begin{align}
g^{-1}(I) &= (g^{-1}(I) \cap A) \cup (g^{-1}(I) \cap A^c)\\
&= g^{-1}(I \cap A ) \cup (f^{-1}(I) \cap A^c )\\
\end{align}

The proof ends off with $\mu(I \cap A) = 0$ and arguing the intersection of the 2 measurable sets is measurable.

What I really want to know is how to justify $$(g^{-1}(I) \cap A) = g^{-1}(I \cap A )?$$ I did a basic check with set inclusions and what I found was if $y \in  g^{-1}(I \cap A )$, $g(y) \in I \cap A$, but this means $g(y) \in A$....

Comment: Actually I think I know why. Because this statement is simply wrong. The correct finisher is to realize that $g^{-1}(I) \cap A \subset A$. By completeness, $\mu(g^{-1}(I) \cap A) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Lebesgue measure.

More simply, let $U=\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ and $V=\{x:f(x)\ne g(x)\}.$ Then U is a measurable set as its complement  $V$ is a measure-zero set. If $W$ is any open set then $$g^{-1}W=(U\cap f^{-1}W)\cup (V\cap g^{-1}W).$$  Now $U$ and $ f^{-1}W$ are measurable sets , and $V \cap g^{-1}W$ is a measurable set because it is a subset of the measure-zero set $V$. So $g^{-1}W$ is a measurable set.

Comment: I wasn't actually asking for a proof...

Comment: I know. I just  don't like subtle or long  proofs in textbooks when there are easy ones based directly on the def'ns.